# Outlook does not load profile after a reboot

Tags: windows-7, windows, microsoft-outlook

I have a client, they have Outlook 2016. We have done a complete reinstall. All the updates, and everytime they reboot Outlook will get stuck on the start up page. Normally on the processing.

We tried safe mode and removing plugins. Nothing works.

The only jury rig that works is this:
Create a new profile. Log into new profile. Close outlook. Switch back to old profile open outlook. It works till you reboot.

Anyone have any ideas on the cause or a fix?

Comment: Why is the old profile needed?  It isn't because of the data files.  If you setup the new profile, with the same accounts, does the new profile exhibit the same behavior?

Comment: Have you tried `scanpst.exe`?

Comment: @root yes I tried that. It made no changes to the issue.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, it does. If you reboot the new account will no longer open like the old one.

Comment: You have all available Outlook updates installed.  IMAP or Exchange?  How many emails are on the server?  How large is the mailbox?

Comment: All updates installed. Outlook 2016. This is a gmail account along with an IMAP I think as well in the mix. No idea in terms of emails in the server but I closed outlook right after adding a new account and even with almost no emails in the PST file it still displayed the same issues.